# Closed the closet door and Kaboom the acorn thumb latch broke off. Looking for a solution to open it

Tags: repair, lock

[image]After I closed my closet door the acorn thumb latch fell apart. The part I depress with my thumb fell off in front and the door is locked. There is a small hole where the thumb piece was inserted, but I can not see much as the hole is small. There is a video on Thumb-klatch install on YouTube so I now believe the piece in the back must be moved up to unlock the door. My two questions are what tool can I insert through the small hole to lift the latch upwards? if that does not work, how can  I remove the two large brass hinges that are holding the door on? Any Tips or knowledge appreciated.

[![The actual door that is locked.][2]][2]

Comment: Ummm...  What image?

Comment: Any piece of thin stock(plastic, thin steel, knife) should work.  Just have to get it in edge of door and jamb.  Might also use a nail and push down where thumb latch was.

Comment: A picture of your actual door will be necessary for us to identify whether or not the "two large brass hinges" can be removed.

Comment: Thank You, I will get a picture loaded sometime today.

Comment: I replaced the photo of a similar door Lock with a photo of the locked door.

Answer (score 2):

A screwdriver (suitably small/thin)

A wire

An ice-pick (right, nobody but old folks has those)

A nail

Pretty much anything that fits through the slot and allows you to lever up the latch bar. That will be easier if you can hold the door in such a way that there is little to no pressure on the latch.

Point the tool of whatever sort downwards as you push it in, then tip and lift it upwards.

It appears that even if you were to remove the hinge pins, the fit of the door in the frame is such that you probably can't pull that side of the door outwards, due to interference by the barrels of the fixed hinge.

If the latch broke, you may be able to just pry up the remaining bit of the latch, if that is still in place.

Depending how the doorframe on the latch side is configured, an old credit card inserted between the door and frame below the latch and moved upwards may also work.

Comment: Hurray, a long and strong tool opened the door. Thanks to all!!!!